# SQLAlchemy double forward slash issue using MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I have searched now for several hours. I am taking Facebook posts and want to parse them into a mysql db using SQLAlchemy in python.
Facebook posts include smileys and a bunch of special characters.

The SQLALCHEMY Database URI look like the following:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqldb://...?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0"

Before committing to the database I am also encoding in utf8:
    string.encode("utf-8")

Testing from several questions/answers here I still run into this issue:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8C\\x9E\\xF0\\x9F...'

Comment: You're on Python 2? If not, [don't use `use_unicode` at all](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#unicode-encoding-decoding). And if you are and want the possible performance gains, let SQLAlchemy handle encoding for you, or in other words don't manually encode. Your question lacks [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so it is hard to say where exactly it happens, but that looks like a result of double  escaping of some kind. Instead of bytes you've got string representations of byte escape sequences (for example produced by error handler backslashreplace).

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä for your comment. Yes I am using 2.7 will add that info to my question and try to improve it for mcve. I also run into the parsing error with double forward quotes if I don't encode the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8`?

[Here's the reference](http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2014/04/24/active-record-mysql-and-emoji/)

Comment: Yes I have. and it results in the same issue.

Comment: @JustusNiemzok - but did you change `?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0`?  _And_ the table/column `CHARACTER SET`?  `utf8mb4` _is_ required for .

Comment: @JustusNiemzok - Do you happen to know which suggestions were required in your situation?

Comment: yes. I did not set the mysql table/column character set to the utf8mb4. After I changed and `?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0` @RickJames

Comment: `True`, not `0`.